# Mercurial: How to include version information in exports?

Tags: mercurial

Sometimes, I need to provide a version of my code to other collaborators without giving them access to the history (everything inside .hg directory). I do this by cloning my repository, updating the clone to the required version and deleting the .hg directory.

Is there a way I can include some information in this export operation that can later tell me which version I had actually passed them? For example, say automatically including the hash in a file or something similar? What is the canonical way to achieve something like this in Mercurial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recent versions of `hg archive` place a `.hg_archival.txt` into the exported directory, which contains the revision of the dump.

```
$ hg archive ../output
$ cat ../output/.hg_archival.txt
repo: ca6f47a3560d95bc168f5d348fd42779537ce007
node: e8da6559282f6d0963ee31870ce1f0dc7e138459
branch: default
latesttag: null
latesttagdistance: 4
```

Comment: Rudi: I was not aware of the archive command. Thanks, this solves my problem :-)

Comment: Filename pattern for archive may include repository-information (local revision number, f.e)

Comment: +1 for hg archive. Really useful command. Working as a contractor I often found myself using it as a delivery mechanism. `hg archive -t tgz tarfilename_%h.tar.gz` useally does what I want. People ask why there's weird numbers in the name the first time, but you just explain it's so you can track the versions of code, and they're happy.

Comment: Paul: Creating exports (or archives in Hg-speak) in these many zip formats is just wow! Such a cool command :-)